# Image doesn't show up in react

Tags: reactjs

I want to add an image in a tinder-clone app. I followed the mern stack tutorial on the clever programmer youtube channel.
Unfortunately, the image didn't show up in the browser.

This is my code:

```
import React, { useState } from 'react';
import TinderCard from "react-tinder-card";
import "./TinderCards.css";

function TinderCards() {
    const [people, setPeople] = useState([
        {
            name: 'Elon Musk',
            url: "https://i.pinimg.com/originals/00/09/f4/0009f44897c3d9f6eb740dea9ec11022.png",
        },
        {
            name: 'Jeff Bezos',
            url:  "https://www.macitynet.it/wp-content/uploads/2017/11/jeff-bezos.jpg",
        },
    ]);

    const swiped = (direction, nameToDelete) => {
        console.log("removing: " + nameToDelete);
    }

    const outOfFrame = (name) => {
        console.log(name + " left the screen!");
    };

    return (
        <div className="tinderCards">
            <div class="tinderCards_cardContainer">
                {people.map((person) => (
                    <TinderCard 
                        className="swipe"
                        key={person.name}
                        preventSwipe={["up", "down"]}
                        onSwipe={(dir) => swiped(dir, person.name)}
                        onCardLeftScreen={() => outOfFrame(person.name)}
                    >
                        <div
                            style={{ backgroudImage: `url(${person.url})` }}
                            className="card"
                        >
                            <h3>{person.name}</h3>
                        </div>
                    </TinderCard>
                ))}
            </div>  
        </div>
    );
}

export default TinderCards;
```

And this is what I see in the browser:
[image]

Does anyone know how to solve this problem?

Thanks!

Emiel

Answer (score 1, accepted):

your mistake is the **background** name, it is not spelled correctly

it should be:

```
style={{ backgroundImage: `url(${person.url})` }
```

**Demo:**
https://stackblitz.com/edit/react-wybpt3?file=src/TinderCards.js

Answer (score 1):

I think you have the typo there,

```
style={{ backgroudImage: `url(${person.url})` }
```

as

```
style={{ backgroundImage: `url(${person.url})` }
```

Also, check that `.card` class has some height and width so that it can apply the background image.